# Windows 7 laptop, SSID is not shown within the available wireless networks

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

Windows 7 laptop, new Wifi router. Router broadcast on 2.4Ghz, the 5Ghz channels disabled.
Recently I noticed that my network SSID is not shown anymore in available wireless networks list,  so connect to the router is not possible. New Wifi router, the other devices can be connected to router via Wifi without problems. A week ago I didn't have such issue, I configured new WiFi connection on my laptop, and everything went fine. All wifi connection settings on Windows laptop is default, worked with previous Wifi routers without any issues.

In network adapter settings, Wireless properties, is checked box "Connect even if the network is not broadcasting its name (SSID)".

I have not used Win7 laptop for a long time, it seems, laptop  stopped show SSID after the Avast upgrade, but I'm not entirely certain. I tried to disable Avast, but this didn't make any changes.

**EDIT:** the issue is solved. 
The problem was in WiFi router. The Trendnet N600 dual band Wifi TEW-752DRU: this device showed itself as a complete rubbish, junk.
When both 2.4GHz and 5GHz is enabled, the **only** 5GHz network SSID is shown and laptop tries to connect to that SSID, but 5GHz signal power is so low (even at 1m distance!), that Win7 laptop never able to connect to that network. I turned off 5GHz wireless, left only 2.4GHz, and set the '802.11 Mode' settings to "Mixed 802.11n and 802.11g", the other combinations just not work. In addition, router seems does not remember the settings that were set. If change one setting, it resets other settings to their default values, and this isn't always noticeable.

Comment: When you refresh the WiFi Networklist in Win7, does it show your network as a network without a SSID? Does it show any other SSIDs? Maybe you could make a screenshot of the Win7 WiFi List and also write the SSID of the network you are looking for.

Comment: The surrounding wireless networks are shown in Wireless Network Connections list, but not mine.

Comment: You should add this information in your question, it's important. When did you setup your router? A week ago? Have you ever connected with the laptop to the WiFi router in the past? In your question you write everything worked a week ago, but then you write that you haven't used the laptop for a long time? Please clarify and add the information to your question.

Comment: Also check if you can log on with the laptop onto another WiFi. If you have a smart phone you could create a hot spot and see if it works.

Comment: *A week ago I didn't have such issue*... Use System Restore to revert your Windows configuration to a state saved prior to when the problem started.

Answer (score 0):

There are already several questions/answers regarding this topic, like this one:

- [Wifi network not showing up on laptop but showing up on phone](https://superuser.com/questions/812155/wifi-network-not-showing-up-on-laptop-but-showing-up-on-phone)

You should go through those answers and check if they already give you the correct solution. Especially the incompatibility with "old" network cards in old laptops can cause issues with a "newer" router. Often the Frequency, the protocol (802.11-whatever) or the encryption is not supported by the network card. Sometimes (especially in case of the encryption) this can be solved by updating the network card driver/software.

There are still too many possible scenarios to check, to write a definitive answer, but it sounds like there it's the same problem as described in the link. You should check that first.

Answer (score 0):

According to OP's edit, this is the Answer:

> The problem was in WiFi router. The Trendnet N600 dual band Wifi
> TEW-752DRU: this device showed itself as a complete rubbish, junk.
> When both 2.4GHz and 5GHz is enabled, the only 5GHz network SSID is
> shown and laptop tries to connect to that SSID, but 5GHz signal power
> is so low (even at 1m distance!), that Win7 laptop never able to
> connect to that network. I turned off 5GHz wireless, left only 2.4GHz,
> and set the '802.11 Mode' settings to "Mixed 802.11n and 802.11g", the
> other combinations just not work. In addition, router seems does not
> remember the settings that were set. If change one setting, it resets
> other settings to their default values, and this isn't always
> noticeable.